# SMPS design with BUCK converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I want to design the SMPS with the following specifications-

1. 5V DC,5Amax,1Amin
2. 12V DC,5Amax,1Amin
3. using BUCK converter.
4. Vin DC=24V

Comment: What yo have so far is just a message, what specific question do you have?

Comment: what an amazing idea! what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have an input voltage of 24 volts (say 23 volts to 25 volts) and you want two outputs; one at 5V (and 5A) and one at 12V, 5A.

The simplest (possibly) way involves going to Linear technology's buck converter [page](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Step-Down_%28Buck%29_Regulators#!1646_Buck!1032_%3C=23!1033_%3E=25!1105_%3C=12!1034_%3E=12!1107_6:13.5!vinmin_23!vinmax_25!vout_12!iout_6!vout2_!iout2_!vout3_!iout3_) and plugging in the numbers for both outputs. The dat entry area above should be setup for an input voltage matching your requirements and 12v for the 1st output. It suggests many devices to choose from.

The [LT8612](http://www.linear.com/product/LT8612) looks good for 5V (or 12V) at 6A and the [LT3845A](http://www.linear.com/product/LT3845A) looks able to provide 12 volts at over 6 amps. There are others on the page also worth looking at.

Should you be wanting a bargain-basement low cost product you didn't say so I went for the technology that I know to be probably the best and one of the devices (LT8612) I've used successfully in a couple of designs.